# What kind of grammar is it in 調査に調査を重ねて?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

I did not find any resources explaining the following grammar.

> N に N を V

For example,

> **調査に調査を重ねて**事故の原因を究明した。

What kind of grammar is it? What does it mean?

Comment: I think the grammar question’s been adequately answered below, but as a translation, I might go with something like “They searched after the cause of the accident, piling investigation on investigation.”

Comment: @DavidMoles Oh, do you have such an expression in English too? That's great! Btw I think I'd say "searched out" rather than "searched after".

Comment: @broccoliforest We do! And I wasn't excited about "searched after". I think "sought out" or even just "sought" might be more natural.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> X に X を重ねる (lit. *to pile up X (further) onto X*)

is an idiomatic phrase to mean "doing X extensively, or unthinkably many times over", usually X is a noun that means some kind of (hard) work.

I also often hear:

> 研究に研究を重ねる
>   努力に努力を重ねる
>   改良に改良を重ねる etc.

Answer (score 7):

> 「N に N を V」 when the verb is 「重{かさ}ねる」

means:

> "to do/make one N after another" or
>
> "to do/make N repeatedly"

「調査{ちょうさ}に調査を重ねる」 thus means "***to conduct one investigation after another***".

Comment: Are there any other verbs?